# Show changes to registers after each instruction

Tags: visual-studio-2010, assembly, x86

In Visual Studio 2010, is it possible to step through an assembly language program and show the changes to all registers after every instruction? I already know that it's possible to watch several different registers using the "watch" option, but I want to know whether it's possible to display each of the registers that have been modified after each assembly instruction has run.

Comment: The "Watch" option makes it possible to select individual registers to watch, but I want to keep track of all registers that are modified when stepping through an assembly language program, instead of just some of them.

Answer (score 2):

There is a special register window in the debugger. Just select Debug->Windows->Registers in the menu to make it visible.

When you single step assembly code, the changed registers will turn red on each step.

Comment: Would it be possible to display all of the variables as well as the registers?